# Navbar fixed top pos. absolute change to relative when scroll

Tags: jquery, css, navbar

I want to change navbar fixed top position from absolute to relative when scrolls more than 600px.
I have this code:

```
   if (scroll >= 700) {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("navbar-scroll");
  } else {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("navbar-scroll");
   }
});
```

this is working, but I tried to change it to animate( for transition )

and I did this:

```
 if (scroll >= 700) {
                $(".navbar-fixed-top").animate ({
        position: 'fixed'
        }, "slow"); 
} else {
                $(".navbar-fixed-top").animate ({
        position: 'absolute'
        }, "slow");
 }
});
```

and this isnt working, why?

Comment: I think that beginning of scrip are missing, please post full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as how you can't animate the position property, just use absolute positioning and animate the top value instead.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/3KBWU/3/)**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 700) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").animate({
            top: scroll + 10
        }, 50);
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").animate({
            top: '10px'
        },50);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't get it, in ur example navbar is fixed top until scroll is 700px, and then dissapear. But I want exactly the opposite, I mean, navbar gets fixed top after 700px, before that it remais top ( absolute,not fixed ). see example here: http://getflywheel.com/ , scroll arround 800px and you'll see that a navbar appears

Comment: @user2606561 sorry about that I flipped the operator see update

Comment: its working now, thanks! but how can I change background-color of navbar-fixed-top when  scroll >= 700? p.s.: how can I give u +1?

Comment: @user2606561 you can't vote yet, but you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217863 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate the css property `position`, from the JQUERY API DOCS:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; **most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality** (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/